# I am trying to store value of JSON data in an array from servlet but it shows posts.map is not function

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

```
import React,{Component} from "react"
import axios from "axios"
import { List } from "@material-ui/core"

class PostList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            posts:[]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/1706583/dummyServlet')

        .then(response=>{
            console.log(response.data)
            this.setState({posts:response.data})
        })

        .catch(error =>{
            console.log("error in post list"+error)
        })
    }
    render(){
        const {posts}=this.state
        return(
            <div>
                List of posts{
                posts.length ?
                posts.map(post=><div key={post.acct_doc_header_id}>{post.company_id}</div>):
                null
            }

            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default PostList
```

Comment: May be `posts` is not an array ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the state first, because when your request is still pending you have no array in the `posts` state.

And also make sure you get an array from the server. If the response is a string, you need to parse the JSON first using `JSON.parse(myData);`

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    posts: []
  };
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code works fine.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { List, ListItem } from "@material-ui/core";

class PostList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")

      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.setState({ posts: response.data });
      })

      .catch(error => {
        console.log("error in post list" + error);
      });
  }
  render() {
    const { posts } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <List>
          {posts.length
            ? posts.map(post => (
                <ListItem key={post.id}>
                  {post.id}
                  {" - "}
                  {post.title}
                </ListItem>
              ))
            : null}
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PostList;
```